# Lua: Get table value within itself

Tags: lua, scope, lua-table

So I'm trying something which i think should be very easy, but I just can't get it to work...

Basically what I'm trying to do is:

```
myTable = {
  a = 1,
  b = a + 1
}
```

This is not working, I get the error that "a" is nil. Reasonable.
What i have already tried is

```
myTable = {
  a = 1,
  b = myTable.a + 1
}
```

and

```
myTable = {
  a = 1,
  b = self.a + 1
}
```

But it gives me the error me that "myTable"/"self" is nil.

I got the feeling that the solution is rather simple but i couldn't find it out by myself and google wasn't that helpful as well.

Comment: Note that for attempt#3, there is no context for `self` (requires a method definition) so it would reference the global `self` (which would likely be `nil`).

Answer (score 4):

There's no way of doing this in one statement (at least not without calling any functions or using metatables). That's because in a statement like `foo = bar`, the foo variable isn't assigned until the bar expression has been evaluated.

In your second example, the `myTable` variable isn't assigned until the closing curly brace, so the `myTable` in `myTable.a + 1` is treated as an unnassigned global variable, and gets a value of `nil`. The `self` in your third example is the same, only you don't try to assign anything to it later. (In Lua, `self` is only special inside functions written with the colon syntax.)

To do what you want to do, you have to do something like this:

```
myTable = {
    a = 1
}
myTable.b = myTable.a + 1
```

Or this:

```
local a = 1
myTable = {
    a = a,
    b = a + 1
}
```